# Orgmode Spreadsheet: update formula when adding new column

Tags: org-table, formula, spreadsheet

I have a small square *orgmode spreadsheet* with some data in it and 2 extra columns to the right with some formulas, like average and sum.
I want to add some new columns in the middle of my spreadsheet in order to input more data.

**Question:** Is there a way to update all formulas automatically in order to include the new columns?

*Example:* =vsum($2..$12) and I'm adding two new columns, so I want the formula to be updated to =vsum($2..$14); since there are many formulas, I want them all to be updated automatically

Comment: Which spreadsheet?

Comment: orgmode, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically every table manipulating function is updating formulas. For example : <kbd>M-S-right</kbd> includes a new column (before the cursor) updating formulas to the new number of columns.

<kbd>C-u C-c *</kbd> is recalculating all your formulas in the spreadsheet.

Also a <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> on a `#+tblfm:` line is (re)applying all the formulas in the table.

For more advanced stuff, like automatically recalculating please have a look at the [org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-features.html#Advanced-features%20manual).

Comment: To expand: Almost every column/row manipulating command for `org-table` updates the function definitions.

Comment: @Jonathan Leech-Pepin: Right, I was too focused on operations for columns, , will update my answer !

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there were such commands. This solves my problem! Thanks!!! :D

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé: You're welcome! And yes org-mode is ingenious... :-)

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm Should the formula update the moment I have inserted the column?  I'm using the insert column shortcut and my formulas are not updated and I"m not asked to confirm formula updates.  Checked the source for the insert column function and it has code for fixing formulas, but it doesn't work.